# .click() not working. Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, buttonclick

In my login.aspx I am trying to perform simple client side validation (check Username and password fields are empty or not) on the click of the button. But the .click() in the jquery is not firing. Where am i going wrong.

Note : I have an event LoginButton_Click on the code behind which has some functionality.

```
<script src="Scripts/Login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <td align="right" colspan="2">
     <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"  Text="Log In" 
       onclick="LoginButton_Click" class ="validateForm" />
</td>
```

My login.js file :

```
$(function () {

  $('#LoginButton').click(function () {

            var username = $('#txtUserName');
            var pwd = $('#txtPassword');
            if (username.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("User Name is required.");
                return false;
            }
            if (pwd.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("Password is required.");
                return false;
            }

        });
});
```

Thanks in advance

BB

Comment: is it related to C#????  Remove C# tag...

Comment: More people could help if you posted what the browser actually sees (after server processing), not the ASP version of your page.

Comment: @jfriend00 it turns out that would also be what the browser sees, because he is incorrectly using asp.net tags in a file not processed by asp.net

Comment: Using the jQuery selectors engine you should not have any problems selecting the element like this $("input[id$=LoginButton]") see my answer below.

Comment: are you not going to accept any answer?

Answer (score 4):

`$("#<%= LoginButton.ClientID %>")` does not work on external JavaScript files. If you want to use an external file, create a global variable in the aspx file and access it in the JavaScript file.

---

**Edit:**

create global variable in aspx file.

`var loginButtonId = <%= LoginButton.ClientID %>;`

use it in the JavaScript File

```
$("#" + loginButtonId ).click(function () {...});
```

***note:*** variable should declare before adding the reference to JavaScript file.

Comment: I changed to $('#LoginButton').click(function () now i get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

Answer (score 2):

This should not give you any problems, using jquery selectors we select it by its id attribute which ends with LoginButton.

```
$(function () {
  $("input[id$=LoginButton]").click(function () {

            var username = $("input[id$=txtUserName]");
            var pwd = $("input[id$=txtPassword]");
            if (username.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("User Name is required.");
                return false;
            }
            if (pwd.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("Password is required.");
                return false;
            }

        });
});
```

Comment: thank you.  i get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected". I tried all the solution mentioned here but I am getting the same error.

Comment: My bad forgot to also select the user and password elements in the same way. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want *onclientclick*.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Just in case someone out there cares...

```
<script src="Scripts/Login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <td align="right" colspan="2">
     <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"  Text="Log In" 
       onclick="LoginButton_Click" onclientclick="validateLogin()" class ="validateForm" />
</td>
```

login.js file :

```
function validateLogin() {

            var username = $('#txtUserName');
            var pwd = $('#txtPassword');
            if (username.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("User Name is required.");
                return false;
            }
            if (pwd.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("Password is required.");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
}
```

Comment: Not correct. He's trying to use jQuery to set the client side code.

Comment: Fine <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"  Text="Log In" 
       onclick="LoginButton_Click" class ="validateForm" ClientIDMode="Static" /> and $("#LoginButton") voila

Comment: I am using jQuery. I don't think I need to have OnClientClick

Comment: Set your clientidmode and you've got it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: @mikey, it didn't help either.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .net version 4.0.   i get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

Answer (score 1):

because in your .js file, javascript couldn't read the value of this: `$("#<%= LoginButton.ClientID %>")`
You need to:
- Put this code at the end of your html page.
OR
- Put a fixed selector in the js file

Answer (score 1):

`#LoginButton` doesn't exist. When the asp button gets rendered it will get rendered into a specialized ID related to the ASP controls that contain it like `ctrl00_mycontrol_panelid_LoginButton`. What you need to do in order to bring this into an external file is use a global variable:

```
var loginButtonID;
var txtUserNameID;
var txtPasswordID;

$(function () {

  $(loginButtonID).click(function () {

            var username = $(txtUserNameID);
            var pwd = $(txtPasswordID);
            if (username.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("User Name is required.");
                return false;
            }
            if (pwd.val().length <= 0) {
                alert("Password is required.");
                return false;
            }

        });
});
```

Then in the file that includes this login.js file, you need to set these variables by calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

loginButtonID = '<%=LoginButton.ClientID%>';
txtUserNameID = '<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>';
txtPasswordID = '<%=txtPassword.ClientID%>';

</script>
```

Be sure not to redeclare these with new "var" modifiers. That may ruin the scope and screw up your script.

Comment: thank you. i get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected".

Comment: @Bumblebee: That means you haven't provided the client ID properly. You should set some alerts or use firebug to determine the status of the javascript variables in question.